# File Size VS Curl Content-Length

Tags: curl, filesize, stat, content-length

I would like to have the same size of the automatic Content-Length header.

I will explain with examples :

When I do this : `echo "testing" | wc -c` // The result is : 8

or

When I do this : `stat -c '%s' "test.txt"` (on a file who contain the word : "testing") // The result is 8

BUT

When I do this : `curl -v -d "testing" http://www.google.fr` // The result is Content-Length: 7

OR

When I do this : `curl -v -d "@test.txt" http://www.google.fr` // The result is Content-Length: 7

Why ?

How can I have the same size ?

Thank you for your help.

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` adds a newline character, so 7 + newline = 8

The `curl` -d option sends only the quoted characters.

To suppress the newline use `-n', this will give 7:

```
echo -n "testing" | wc -c
```

or use `printf` instead:

```
printf "testing" | wc -c
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use printf with files.

Comment: It depends on the files - do these files contain new lines or end of file chars (EOL/EOF)? Are they text or binary files? What is the file size according to your OS?

Comment: This is binary files. I can't find a way to have the same size of curl. Do you know how curl create the Content-Length header ?

Comment: Give an example of a file (with file size as reported by OS), the curl command you're using to post it, and the Content-Length sent. The Content-Length is the actual number of bytes in the request body, so it will either be the number of bytes in the file, or the number of bytes used to _encode_ the file.

Comment: This file for example : http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/

`stat -c '%s' "avatar.jpg"` give 2637

`curl -v -d "@avatar.jpg" http://www.google.fr` give 882

Comment: The `-d` option is for posting a url encoded form, not binary data.. Use `--data-binary` instead

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand now where was my mistake.